# App getting crashed even if no modification done to the code and the stack trace is same as the repackaged version of original app

Tags: apk, zip, file-archives

My question is related to the repackaging of a mobile app. This app uses [v1 signing scheme](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning#v1) and I did the following:

I fetched the apk file from the playstore using `adb` and I signed with my keystore using `apksigner`. Now, when I launch this app on my smartphone, it is showing the following exception.

[image]

I took the original apk, I change the format to *.`zip` and unzipped it, and then again, converted back to apk and I  applied `zipalign` on the apk. The apk gets successfully installed on the smartphone but when I launch this app, I am getting the following exception.
[image]

In this scenario, I didn't modify any file. In the past, I have done this same process for few app's apk and the app is running successfully.

If you observe the above two exception's image, the 1st three lines are same.

My doubt is:

- Irrespective of the signature change, we are getting the same
  exception (atleast the 1st three lines). What can be the reasons
  regarding the same? (Also, I have used the zipalign for the proper
  alignment)
- Which type of framework this app is using such that even without changing the source code, the app is getting crashed?

Any help/inputs regarding this domain is highly appreciated.

Comment: The app seems to be obfuscated and may use invalid file names, therefore just unpacking and repackaging can already change the app. Make sure to unpack only on Linux as it has best support for abnormal file-names, is case-sensitive by default and has less restrictions regarding special file-names.

Comment: Hi @Robert, I tried Linux also. But for that case, the apk generated file seems to be invalid. Hence the app won't even install. But when I used the WinRar Software on Windows OS, atleast, I am able to install.